# Bootstrap Tooltip default styling not right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying a very simple tooltip integration in Bootstrap but getting some weird results:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();

});
</script>

<select title="Tooltip on top" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" id="purchaseddate1-day" name="purchaseddate1-day" class="form-control"><option value="">All</option><option value="1">1</option></select>
```

The tooltip is 100% the width of the screen, grey background and above the element. Why isn't it small, sleek, black and above like specified?

I include the standard js and css:

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: It appears to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/Careless/52VtD/3015/

Comment: So it does! I found this in my <head> which was conflicting it with it:

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>

Comment: I do need the UI javascript though. Any idea why there is a conflict?

Comment: Probably because they both use the same `.tooltip()` method.

Comment: So if I want a datepicker I should be using another one?

Answer (score 0):

"Sometimes it is necessary to use Bootstrap plugins with other UI frameworks. In these circumstances, namespace collisions can occasionally occur. If this happens, you may call `.noConflict` on the plugin you wish to revert the value of.

```
var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict() // return $.fn.button to previously assigned value
$.fn.bootstrapBtn = bootstrapButton            // give $().bootstrapBtn the Bootstrap functionality
```

"

from [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-noconflict)